# How to order and group rows in a query by a master id

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to write a select query in Oracle in which the results are 'isolated' by groups. Each group has a parent entity which has some children so I want to group rows in a way that each group starts with a parent entity followed by the corresponding children.

Table has the following structure:

```
ID | CREATION_DATE       | MASTER_ID
33 | 2019-07-01 09:31:04 | null
52 | 2019-07-01 10:45:04 | null
64 | 2019-07-01 11:00:04 | 33
71 | 2019-07-01 11:01:04 | 52
72 | 2019-07-01 12:31:04 | 33
```

So far I tried the following code which return the rows not grouped by MASTER_ID but ordered correctly by the CREATION_DATE:

```
SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, MASTER_ID
FROM ENTITY
WHERE CREATION_DATE >= TO_DATE('06-01-2019','MM-DD-YYYY')
ORDER BY CREATION_DATE DESC
```

I want to find a way to return the following structure:

```
ID | CREATION_DATE       | MASTER_ID
33 | 2019-07-01 09:31:04 | null
64 | 2019-07-01 11:00:04 | 33
72 | 2019-07-01 12:31:04 | 33
52 | 2019-07-01 10:45:04 | null
71 | 2019-07-01 11:01:04 | 52
```

The issue is that parent entity is `null` all the time so I can't use `GROUP BY`.
Do you have any advice how should I work on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the `connect by` hierarchical query, along with `order siblings by` clause, e.g.:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 33 ID, to_date('2019-07-01 09:31:04', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') creation_date, NULL master_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 52 ID, to_date('2019-07-01 10:45:04', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') creation_date, NULL master_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 72 ID, to_date('2019-07-01 12:31:04', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') creation_date, 33 master_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 64 ID, to_date('2019-07-01 11:00:04', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') creation_date, 33 master_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 71 ID, to_date('2019-07-01 11:01:04', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') creation_date, 52 master_id FROM dual)
SELECT ID,
       creation_date,
       master_id,
       connect_by_root(ID) top_id
FROM   your_table
START WITH master_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = master_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY creation_date;

        ID CREATION_DATE  MASTER_ID     TOP_ID
---------- ------------- ---------- ----------
        33 01/07/2019 09                    33
        64 01/07/2019 11         33         33
        72 01/07/2019 12         33         33
        52 01/07/2019 10                    52
        71 01/07/2019 11         52         52
```

Comment: Nice, this works correctly! Thanks a lot!
Do you have an idea how to make it work fine when the parent entity has 0 instead of null and there are still other rows with null but not 'parents'?

Comment: `start with master_id = 0`?

Comment: yes, but also show the rows with master_id = null ordered correct by date

Comment: Add in an `or parent_id is null`?

Comment: Basically I have rows with MASTER_ID with the following values: null, 0 or integer values (reference to ID column). And I want to group rows starting with value 0, so each group starts with "parent" which has 0 followed by "children" with ID of the "parent" but other rows which have null as value should also appear in the result before or after a group ordered by date. I tried this but events with null doesn't appear: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=65c81bfb9bdb86746fef70c17fb1015e

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ad879da967d66085d452f1e0e9856390 ? I added in `or master_id is null` as per my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simple to order by with dynamic column.

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 33 ID, to_date('2019-07-01 09:31:04', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') creation_date, NULL master_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 52 ID, to_date('2019-07-01 10:45:04', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') creation_date, NULL master_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 72 ID, to_date('2019-07-01 12:31:04', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') creation_date, 33 master_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 64 ID, to_date('2019-07-01 11:00:04', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') creation_date, 33 master_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 71 ID, to_date('2019-07-01 11:01:04', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') creation_date, 52 master_id FROM dual)
SELECT
    ID,
    CREATION_DATE,
    MASTER_ID
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            CREATION_DATE,
            MASTER_ID,
            CASE
                WHEN MASTER_ID IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END AS RN
        FROM
            YOUR_TABLE
        ORDER BY
            CASE
                WHEN MASTER_ID IS NULL THEN ID
                ELSE MASTER_ID
            END,
            RN
    );
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9d22b5b0bc6e47844cd14b153012be0a)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one level of hierarchy, then you can simply do:

```
select t.*
from t
order by coalesce(t.master_id, t.id),
         t.creation_date
```